# Button on the phone is triggering nothing but the lightbox popup

Tags: javascript

The button on small devices is not working. The button is supposed to open an external application form as a lightbox popup. I want to be able to trigger some other code as the button is clicked. To test it I used the alert() method, but it only worked on the desktop. On the other hand, the phone only triggers the popup but not the alert().

The website was developed on Wordpress.

this is the script:

```
 document.addEventListener(
      'mousedown',
      function (event) {
        if (event.target.innerHTML == 'Apply now' ) {
          alert('Button Clicked')
        }
      }
    );
```

And this is how the button is presented on the DOM:

```
<a class="typeform-share common-btn" target="_blank" data-mode="2" href="form_link"><span>Apply now</span></a>
```

Comment: Share some code, preferably a reproducible example. We can't help if we can't see what the issue is.

Comment: Ok, I added some code.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering your click event listener on the document. You need to register it on the button itself. You can use the "click" event as opposed to the mousedown. Also, since there is a `<span>` tag within the button, `innerHTML` won't work for you. You should use `innerText`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.typeform-share').forEach(btn => {
    if( btn.innerText == 'Apply now' ) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            alert('Button Clicked');
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<a class="typeform-share common-btn" target="_blank" data-mode="2" href="form_link"><span>Apply now</span></a>
```

Comment: But I thought to use Event Delegation and only the elements that have "Apply now" as an innerText should execute the code.That button was made with some plugin and I can't simply add an id to it unless I use code to append it, which is what I wanted to avoid from the beginning.

Comment: Understood. I updated the answer to find any button with the class that was already supplied, and then, if the content is "Apply now", register the event. It will do this for each and every button it finds on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's still not working on the phone. It only calls the href !!

Comment: I would try to debug on the phone... Are you sure WordPress is outputting the same content for mobile? If something is different about the HTML, then it won't work. Plugins could affect this.

Comment: I compared both devices on the responsive console tool but I'll check with the developer who created the theme. That's a possibility. I'll reply back once I get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question. Just in case somebody faces the same problem.

The problem was in the interaction of the touch devices. They recognized `touchstart` and not just `click` which I don't know why this happened in this situation. But using jQuery and changing `click` to `touchstart click` worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.typeform-share').on('touchstart click', function () {
    alert('btn clicked');
  });
});
```